# Will running a pruned node make my store less secure?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, pruning

We run our own nodes to verify transactions for our store and I was wondering what will be the downsides to me running a pruned node? I read they can fully verify a transaction so I'm not too sure why I need a full copy of the blockchain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will running a pruned node make my store less secure?

No, not at all.

> I was wondering what will be the downsides to me running a pruned node?

With a pruned node you cannot:

- Handle (extremely) deep reorganizations (which are in theory possible but in practice would indicate a very serious problem with Bitcoin's security assumptions).
- Serve old blocks to other nodes.
- Rescan for old transactions that may affect your wallet after importing an old address/key.

> I'm not too sure why I need a full copy of the blockchain.

You generally don't, apart from the cases listed above.